# Implementation of arbitrary-precision integer addition

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel, fixed-point

**Implementation:**

```
string Add(string a,string b)
{
    int maxLen = Math.Max(a.Length,b.Length);
    a = a.PadLeft(maxLen+1,'0');
    b = b.PadLeft(maxLen+1,'0');

    int[] arr1 = a.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
    int[] arr2 = b.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
    int[] sum = new int[arr1.Length];

    int carry = 0;
    for(int i = sum.Length-1;i >= 0;i--)
    {
        int total = arr1[i] + arr2[i] + carry;
        sum[i] = total % 10;
        if(total > 9) carry = 1;
        else carry = 0;
    }
    return string.Join("",sum.SkipWhile(x => x == 0));
}
```

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    string a = "12121213213213902139210903";
    string b = "1213212222132132113";
    Console.WriteLine(Add(a,b)); // 12121214426426124271343016
}
```

How can I improve this implementation?

Comment: I don't know C#, but I think you can replace your two lines of carry logic with carry = total / 10.

Comment: @raptortech97 Yeah it works. But i think `carry = total > 9 ? 1 : 0;` is clearer.

Comment: Why not use the [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) struct?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I improve this implementation?

You could extract the string parsing to a separate `int[] ToIntArray(String)` method.
You could add a separate `int[] Add(int[],int[])` method.
You could add a separate `String ToString(int[])` method.

Right now your method is

1. parsing the `String`'s to `int[]`
2. adding two `int[]`
3. composing a `string` out of the adding

So after extracting the methods your former `Add()` method would look like

```
string Add(string a,string b)
{
    int maxLen = Math.Max(a.Length,b.Length);
    a = a.PadLeft(maxLen+1,'0');
    b = b.PadLeft(maxLen+1,'0');

    int[] arr1 = ToIntArray(a);
    int[] arr2 = ToIntArray(b);

    int[] sum = Add(arr1,arr2);

    return ToString(sum);
}
```

But wait, we can do much better using more OOP.

Let us introduce a new class `IntArray` ( which can be private ). In this class we override the `ToString()` method, add constructors for `int[]` and `string` and also add a `+ operator`.

```
private class IntArray
{

    public int[] array { get; private set; }
    public IntArray(int[] arr)
    {
        array = arr;
    }

    public IntArray(String s)
    {
        array = s.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
    }

    public static IntArray operator +(IntArray summand1, IntArray summand2)
    {
        int[] sum = new int[summand1.array.Length];
        int carry = 0;

        for (int i = sum.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int total = summand1.array[i] + summand2.array[i] + carry;
            sum[i] = total % 10;
            if (total > 9) 
            {
                 carry = 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                carry = 0;
            }
        }

        return new IntArray(sum);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat(array.SkipWhile(x => x == 0));
    }

}
```

This will simplify your former `Add()` method to

```
string Add(string a, string b)
{
    int maxLen = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
    a = a.PadLeft(maxLen + 1, '0');
    b = b.PadLeft(maxLen + 1, '0');

    IntArray arr1 = new IntArray(a);
    IntArray arr2 = new IntArray(b);

    return (arr1 + arr2).ToString();
}
```

Update: Based on [d347hm4n](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46280/d347hm4n)'s comment and after checking the reference source, I changed to implementation of `ToString()` from `String.Join()` to `String.Concat()` method.

Comment: In your ToString() is it not better to use:     string.Concat(array.SkipWhile(x => x == 0));

Comment: Don't you think you reinvented a lite version of the [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) struct?

Comment: @Dmitry I have added the `reinventing-the-wheel` tag to the question.

Comment: @d347hm4n Didn't know about that overload of string.Concat.

Answer (score 2):

On my opinion, you don't need to parse a `string`'s elements as `int`, you could address a particular digit as a `char`.

```
private static string Add(string a, string b)
{
    const string ArgumentExceptionString = "Argument is not represents a decimal number";

    int maxLen = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length) + 1;
    a = a.PadLeft(maxLen, '0');
    b = b.PadLeft(maxLen, '0');

    char[] sum = new char[a.Length];
    int carry = 0;

    // The low loop margin is raised up to 1, because we don't need arithmetics for the 
    // first char, it can be only '0' or '1':
    for (int i = sum.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int aDigit = a[i] - '0';
        if (aDigit < 0 || aDigit > 9)
            throw new ArgumentException(ArgumentExceptionString, "a");

        int bDigit = b[i] - '0';
        if (bDigit < 0 || bDigit > 9)
            throw new ArgumentException(ArgumentExceptionString, "b");

        int total = aDigit + bDigit + carry;
        sum[i] = (char)('0' + (total % 10));
        carry = total > 9 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    // Process the first char:
    sum[0] = (char)('0' + carry);
    // Return the entire `sum` chars if carry == 0, or return it without the first digit:
    return new String(sum, 1 - carry, maxLen - 1 + carry);
}
```

This approach should improve a performance.

Comment: This might be faster, but it's certainly not cleaner.

Comment: @raptortech97 Maybe you're right, but the OP's question is `How can I improve this implementation?` Thus a performance is also an option.

Comment: You could reuse the `maxLen` for creating of the `sum` array and also for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog

> *34. The string is a stark data structure and everywhere it is passed there is much duplication of process. It is a perfect vehicle for
>   hiding information.*
>   --Alan J. Perlis, [Epigrams on Programming](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/perlis-alan/quotes.html)

## Multiple Precision Arithmetic

Knuth, in *The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms; third edition*, describes the classic addition algorithm for multiple precision arthmetic [ie. the sort of arithmetic we do every day by hand]:

- Addition of *n*-place integers giving an *n*-place answer and a carry.
- *n*-place integer addition is built from addition of one place integers, giving a one place integer and a carry.
- Defining "*n*-place integer" as `b^n` where `b` "is the radix of ordinary positional notation in which the numbers are expressed".

The key however is:

> *The most important fact to understand about extended-precision numbers is that they may be regarded as numbers writing in radix* w
>   *notation, where* w *is the computer's word size. For example, an integer that fills 10 words on a computer whose word size is* `w =  10^10` *has 100 decimal digits;* **but we will consider it to be a
>   10-place number to the base 10^10**. *This viewpoint is justified for
>   the same reason that we may convert, say, from binary to hexadecimal
>   notation, simply by grouping the bits together.* [page 266].

Algorithm A and Program A which follow provide implementation details but in general these may be seen as equivalent to digital circuits for addition.

## Resources

1. [C# BigInteger Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class) at Code Project.
2. [BigInteger](http://biginteger.codeplex.com/releases/view/16762) at Codeplex.
3. StackOverflow question [1340397](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340397/a-more-simple-big-adder-in-c).

Comment: Ok, you explained what Multiple Precision Arithmetic is and how can you use it. How is that related to the code in the question?

Comment: @svick "Use numeric methods instead of string methods," answers the question "How can I improve this implementation?" for some meanings of 'improve'. It is theoretically possible to get from New York to London in vehicle made of concrete, but it will need to be a boat, not an aeroplane.